# How To Store List Of Objects In The Database By Hitting The Database Only Once?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to Save a list of Questions in the Database. The Problem is let say "if I have 2000 question in the list" and I want to save that list into the Database, I have to hit the Database 2000 times. How can I avoid this?

My code to save Questions in the Database is:

```
public boolean saveQuestionsToDatabase(List<Question> eventQuestionList)
{
    try
    {
        int saveQuestionCounter = 0;
        for(Question question : eventQuestionList)
        {
            entityManager.merge(question);
            saveQuestionCounter++;
        }

        return (eventQuestionList.size()==saveQuestionCounter);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any Help/Suggestion will really be helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the database?

Comment: Database that I am using is Oracle 10g

Answer (score 0):

You should build single query, where you place all your items of your list.
For example oracle has `INSERT ALL` statement where you can then write multiple inserts which is much faster. Or in MySql you can do so

```
    INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2, Column3 )
    VALUES ('John', 123, 'Question 1'), 
           ('Jane', 124, 'Question 2'), 
           ('Billy', 125, 'Question 3'),
           ('Miranda', 126, 'Question 4');
```

Depends on database you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Batch processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html) like below and set the batch size using `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to 20.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```